# Enviar formulario con selects dinámicos

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Estoy trabajando en un formulario, que clona las filas de una tabla, filas que contienen unos select y una caja de texto, utilizando para ello javascript y la librería jquery.

La duda a resolver es cómo envío la cantidad de selects adicionanos, no se si me haga explicar, pero para aclararlo, espero sirva, pongo este ejemplo que en php funciona en un select:

```html
<select name='calificacion**$i**'>
<option value="0">Seleccionar</option>
<option value="1">ingles</option>
<option value="2">frances</option>
</select>
```

Dónde **$i** sería el número de selects que se van creando; pero no logro acoplar esa referencia (**$i**) en mi script.

Dejo el código de lo que hasta el momento tengo en funcionamiento:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

        $(".idi").change(function(){
                var tr =  $(this).parent().parent();
                idi = $(this).val();
                $.post("getHorarios.php", { idi: idi }, 
                             function(data){
                                tr.find("#hori").html(data); 
                });
       })
       
        $("#adicional").on('click', function(){
       var row = $("#tabla tbody tr:eq(0)").clone(true).removeClass('fila-fija'); 
          row.find('.hori').empty(); 
          row.appendTo("#tabla tbody")
       var count = $("#tabla tbody tr").length;
          $("#count").val(count);
     });
        
        $(".eliminar").on("click",function(){
          var parent = $(this).closest("tr").remove();
          var count = $("#tabla tbody tr").length;
          $("#count").val(count)-1;
        }); 
     
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <form id='form1' name='form1' method='post' action='proceso.php'>
    <table align="center" id="tabla">
                   <thead>
                      <tr>
                         <th>Idiomas</th>
                         <th>Horarios</th>
                         <th>Grupos</th>
                      </tr>
                   </thead>
                   <tbody>
                      <tr>
                         <td>
                            <select class="idi" name="idi">
                               <option value="NULL">Seleccionar</option>
                               <option value="1">ingles</option>
                               <option value="2">frances</option>
                            </select>
                         </td>
                         <td><select name="hori" class="term" id="hori"></select></td>
                         <td><input name='grupos$i' type='text' id='grupos' size='3' maxlength='2'/></td>  
                         <td class="eliminar"><input type="button" value="-"/></td>
                       </tr>
                   </tbody>
                </table>
                
        <table align='center'><tr><td align=center><div><button id='adicional' name='adicional' type='button'>Fila +</button></div></td></tr></table>
        
    <button type='submit' name='submit' id='ok'>Aceptar</button>
    </form>
```

Cómo se puede observar, a medida que se da clic en el botón "fila +", se crea una nueva fila con los select dinámicos y una caja de texto, y necesito enviar cada dato uno de los datos que se diligencien. Sé que debe ser algo básico, pero no logro apreciar qué es, por eso acudo a ustedes por ayuda.

Muchas gracias por los aportes que puedan brindarme.

Answer (score 0):

Checa el codigo que dejo, tienes que usar el name de los input o select con [], asi podras enviar todos los datos y manejarlos como arreglo en php.

Ejemplo de envio:

```js
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "url",
    data: datos,
    dataType: 'json',
}).done(function(jsonResponse) {
// manejar respuesta...
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
            $(".idi").change(function(){
              var tr =  $(this).parent().parent();
             //alert($('.idi').val());
              idi = $(this).val();
              $.post("getIdiomas.php", { idi: idi }, 
              function(data){
                tr.find("#term").html(data); 
              });
            })

            $("#adicional").on('click', function(){
              var row = $("#tabla tbody tr:eq(0)").clone(true).removeClass('fila-fija');
              row.find('.term').empty(); 
              row.appendTo("#tabla tbody")
              //
              var count = $("#tabla tbody tr").length;
              $("#count").val(count);
            });

            $(".eliminar").on("click",function(){
              var parent = $(this).closest("tr").remove();
               var count = $("#tabla tbody tr").length;
              $("#count").val(count)
            });
            
            $("#form").submit(function(e){
              e.preventDefault();
              var datos = $('#form').serialize();
              console.log(datos);
            });
          });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
<table align="center" id="tabla">
               <thead>
                  <tr>
                     <th>IDIOMAS</th>
                     <th>Opciones</th>
                  </tr>
               </thead>
               <tbody>
                  <tr>
                     <td>
                        <select class="idi" name="idiomas[]">
                           <option value="">Seleccionar</option>
                           <option value="1">ingles</option>
                           <option value="2">frances</option>
                        </select>
                     </td>
                     <td><select name="term[]" class="term" id="term"></select></td>
                     <td class="eliminar"><input type="button" value="-"/></td>
                   </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
            
    <table align='center'><tr><td align=center><div><button id='adicional' name='adicional' type='button'>Fila +</button></div></td></tr></table>
    
    <table align='center'><tr><td align=center><div>Filas: <input id='count' type='number'/></div></td></tr></table>
     <button type='submit' name='submit' id='ok'>Aceptar</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: gracias por responder, podrías ilustrarme cómo aplico la función ajax que dejaste?

Comment: @AndrésVillamarín
Al hacer click sobre el boton Aceptar:

$("#form").submit(function(e){
              e.preventDefault();
              var datos = $('#form').serialize();
              $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "procesar_formulario.php",
                  data: datos,
                  dataType: 'json',
               }).done(function(jsonResponse) {
                 // "jsonResponse" es tu respuesta en formato json
              });
 });


En procesar_formulario.php podras recibir la informacion con $_POST['datos'] como un arreglo

Comment: realicé lo que me sugeriste. pero no avanza al siguiente archivo donde se realiza el proceso... Que hace falta?

Comment: Algún comentario que me pueda ayudar?